# How can I find the occurrence of a specific time period of the day between two timestamps?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following table:

```
Id | starts         | ends
1  | 21/10/21 03:00 | 21/10/21 15:00
2  | 22/10/21 04:00 | 24/10/21 18:00
3  | 25/10/21 18:00 | 25/10/21 21:00
```

I would like to find out the hours falling between 23:00 - 06:00 for each ID.
The output should look like,

```
ID | Hours
1  |  3
2  |  16
3  |  0
```

Since its a timestamp and after 24, it returns to 1. I am having a hard time to derive any logic.

Comment: I removed the postgres tag.  I assume you are using Redshift and under the mistaken impression that it is actually similar to Postgres.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ... well in some ways Redshift _is_ similar to Postgres, insofar as the former is based on a fork from a fairly early version of the latter.  So, there are some similarities, although at this point the syntax and behavior can be very different, depending on the query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Postgres 13 is not even particularly similar to Postgres 8 anymore.  And that ignores all the changes that Redshift put in . . . and the functionality it left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gives you the result as you want. Have in mind that you need to test it in more cases.

```
with between_23_06 as (
  SELECT Id
        ,CASE
           WHEN DATE_PART(h, starts) < 6 THEN 6 - DATE_PART(h, starts)
           ELSE 0
         END as starts_bf_6
        ,CASE
           WHEN DATE_PART(h, starts) = 23 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END as ends_af_23
        ,CASE
           WHEN DATE_PART(d, ends) - DATE_PART(d, starts) > 1 THEN (DATE_PART(d, ends) - DATE_PART(d, starts)) * 7
           ELSE 0
         END as all_day
    FROM dwh_staging.drop_me
)
select Id, (starts_bf_6 + ends_af_23 + all_day) as Hours
  from between_23_06 
 order by 1
```